# Windows impersonation LogonUser error

Tags: c#, authentication, impersonation

I am trying to use [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx) to logon to a restricted network share (with windows server 2012 on the head node) from my local machine (windows 8.1), and I can't seem to get it to work.

Both machines are on the same domain (verified), the account I am using is an adminstrator on my local machine, and the account I am trying to impersonate has admin rights on the machine hosting the share.  I can mount the share using the credentials just fine.

But when I run this line of code:

```
bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);
```

I get the following error:
`The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed`
NativeErrorCode 1798.

This seems to occur regardless of what credentials I use- it happens if I use my own (which I know are good!).

I can't seem to find a solution for this- the docs I find are for a different use case (I think), and involve removing a machine (which one?) from the domain and rejoining.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?  Solutions?  Suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Can u access a share or resource on the target machine with RUNAS using an account that has rights on the target ? and they have the same FQDN and the SPN is the same in AD?

Comment: @saj Yep and yep.  I'm thinking it doesn't have anything really to do with the machine I'm trying to access- just trying to retrieve that token fails with several known good credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the answer.  `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` is not right.  `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` is what to use.

On [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) they describe what the variables are, but not the values.  You need to actually go look at the `#define` in `winbase.h` (I found a version [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/b6761db45b70f7def58ec55186574a084836450e/tree/include/winbase.h)) that shows the values for those variables.  In this case, you need to use a logon type value of `9` instead of `2`.  In C# land, it's just a bit more work, but... it works :)

Comment: Sincere thanks for this, since it's the only way I can get my (just under) 800 regression and unit tests to run under Windows 8.1.  I wonder how long it will take the Microsoft (air quotes) security experts (end air quotes) to scream about "security holes!" and stop us from using this.  As a developer I'm really getting sick and tired of MS kicking me in the nuts every other week...

Comment: you rock! thanks my CI server was down because of this.